# One question about homological algebra

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $A$ be an Artin algebra, and $0\rightarrow L\rightarrow M\rightarrow N\rightarrow 0$ a short exact sequence with $pd N<\infty$ in $\text{mod}-A$, where $pd N$ is projective dimension of $N$.

Then why $\Omega^{pd N}(L) \cong \Omega^{pd N}(M)$? Where $\Omega^{i}$ is the $i-\text{th}$ syzygy.

Comment: If you have two different questions, ask them separately, please. Especially if they are not related at all like here!

Comment: OK, thank you, i will remenber it!

Comment: 1: To preserve exact sequences, $F$ should be an exact functor. Maybe it's not worth posting as a separate question.

Comment: @Alejoe Exact functor preserve short exact sequence, but i am not sure it preserve long exact sequence .

Comment: To question 2, you can look at the Horseshoe lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_lemma

Comment: @jin zhang Any long exact sequence may be decomposed into short exact sequences. A quick search shows that this question has been answered various times on this site: see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207551/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803578/

Comment: @Alejo I get it. And how about if $F$ is equivalence?

Comment: @Penson I get it, thank you very much!

Comment: @jin zhang An equivalence of categories is both left adjoint and right adjoint, hence preserves all colimits and limits, in particular cokernels and kernels, so it is exact.

Comment: @DonAlejo Yes, you are right, thank you!